# SQL search between 2 dates

Tags: mysql

Hi I have a database table with date of different dates and year..

i used this code 
**select * from salesinvoice where Date Between '01/01/2015' AND '01/31/2015'**

but the output has a JAN 2014 dates

what could be the problem thanks for the advice

Comment: What is the datatype of `Date` in the table ?

Comment: varchar sir @AbhikChakraborty

Comment: And you save data as `01/01/2015` in the table ?

Comment: you cannot use between when the data (date) is in string format.

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty yes sir i save it using a date chooser ..

Comment: @Arzgethalm but sir there is still a result the only problem is that 2014 is being included

Answer (score 2, accepted):

convert it first to date datatype:

```
 select * from salesinvoice where str_to_date(Date,'%m/%d/%Y') Between str_to_date('01/01/2015','%m/%d/%Y') AND str_to_date('01/31/2015','%m/%d/%Y');
```

Comment: You may need to convert the `Date` to real date using str_to_date as well since OP is storing date as varchar in `m/d/Y`  format.

Comment: No query(s) were executed. Please enter a query in the SQL window or place the cursor inside a query.

Comment: @MacChing check for the updated answer, Abhik,thank you for that, I updated the query. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
select * from salesinvoice where Date >= '01/01/2015' and Date <= '01/31/2015'
```

Comment: sir the result is the same